# Is there a way to generate Thrift structure from a json string without having a .thrift file? Is it possible for protobuf?

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, microservices, thrift, grpc

We are trying to write a microservice system in golang.
To that end we needed to define some transports for inter-service communication.
One of the ideas was to have the services communicate just via json strings and object type. The service receiving the call would then extract the data from the json string and further process it using a known/expected data-structure based on the object type.

But this method adds an overhead of creating a json string from the structure every time we need to make an rpc call.

We were scoping out which RPC to use: Thrift or gRPC

And the decision will depend on the fact which one provides a better way to pass data from s client to server with minimal overhead. Basically which RPC can provide a runtime transport structure creation?

Comment: Both are based on some kind of IDL. If you omit the IDL you will have a hard time. Maybe Avro could be of more help if you want to stick to amorphous JSON data, but my experience with Avro is only theoretical so that may not even work. You have to make a decision if you prefer amorphous undefined structures, or want to use gRPC, Thrift or the like, giving up the amorphous. You can't have both (as you want it), I'm afraid.

Comment: "*using a known/expected data-structure*" -- If it is known and expected, define it in IDL, and your all set. But from what you wrote around that in your question I am not so sure if that premise really holds ... that's why I wrote "amorphous data".

Answer (score 0):

for `protobuf`, here is a useful tool:

```
https://json-to-proto.github.io/
```

In terms of `thrift`, I found nothing.